# Equality of an operator equation

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{H}$ a closed convex subspace. Let $P:H\to \mathcal{C}$ be a projection, $A_1,A_2:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ be bounded linear operators and $Id$ the identity operator.

What would be the an approach to show that:

$P(A_1+\mu Id)^{-1}A_1f=P(A_2+\mu Id)^{-1}A_2f$

where $f\in\mathcal{H}$ and $\mu>0$. It is obvious that the equation holds for $\mu=0$. I know that this is not a very specific question but maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by a projection?

Comment: A bounded linear operator that is idempotent (PP = P) and self-adjoint (P=P^*).

Comment: Let $M_j(\mu) = (A_j + \mu \operatorname{Id})^{-1}$ for $j = 1,2$.  Then your statement is equivalent to showing that the image of $M_1(\mu) - M_2(\mu)$ lies in the kernel of $P$, i.e. the orthogonal complement to your closed subspace.

Comment: A subspace is automatically convex. I suspect you are missing some additional  assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you are asking now.

Comment: You are certainly missing some asusmptions. Why would $A_{1,2}+\mu$ be invertible? And if this equality is supposed to hold for any projection $P$, it would imply $(A_1+\mu)^{-1}A_1=(A_2+\mu)^{-1}A_2$, which is not true unless $\mu=0$ or $A_1=A_2$.